# Flutter - Why slider doesn't update in AlertDialog?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I doing a AlertDialog, so when I tried to insert Slider widget inside the state of value sound realy stranger, and this doesn't happens if Slider is outside of AlertDialog

```
new Slider(
  onChanged: (double value) {
    setState(() {
      sliderValue = value;
    });
  },
  label: 'Oi',
  divisions: 10,
  min: 0.0,
  max: 10.0,
  value: sliderValue,
)
```

The complete widget code of AlertDialog

```
Future<Null> _showDialog() async {
  await showDialog<Null>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Criar novo cartão'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(null);
            }, child: new Text('Hello'))
          ],
          content: new Container(
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text('Deseja iniciar um novo cartão com quantos pedidos ja marcados?'),
                new Slider(
              onChanged: (double value) {
                setState(() {
                  sliderValue = value;
                });
              },
              label: 'Oi',
              divisions: 10,
              min: 0.0,
              max: 10.0,
              value: sliderValue,
            )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
  );
}
```

and everything is under State class of StatefullWidget.

Its look like doesn't update the value and when try to change the value keep in same position.

#### Update 1

The problem is there are 2 required parameters in Slider `(onChanged, value)`, So I shoud update this or UI keep quite, see the video how the aplication is running

[Video on Youtube](https://youtu.be/nyLmhDvqJ4U)

#### Update 2

I've also opened a issue to get help with this at Github repository, if someone wants to get more information can go to [issue #19323](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19323)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that it's not your dialog that holds the state. It's the widget that called `showDialog`. Same goes for when you call `setState`, you are calling in on the dialog creator.

The problem is, dialogs are *not* built inside `build` method. They are on a different widget tree. So when the dialog creator updates, the dialog won't.

Instead, you should make your dialog stateful. Hold the data inside that dialog. And then use `Navigator.pop(context, sliderValue)` to send the slider value back to the dialog creator.

The equivalent in your dialog would be

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(sliderValue),
  child: Text("Hello"),
)
```

Which you can then catch inside the `showDialog` result :

```
final sliderValue = await showDialog<double>(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => MyDialog(),
)
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay, so first thanks, but what about the required methods on Slider (onChange, value) both are required, if I set any value that I can't update the state on user try to move the Slider it keeps on the same place, I think if I changethis will keep the same, the slider updates the state just when close, but the problem is when user drag to move, there is no changes

Comment: I've also edit the question to add a video showing this

Comment: It worked! Sorry, I'm starting now with flutter, so I got confused about somethings... thanks again

Comment: @remi-rousselet I think I'm missing how you "make your dialog stateful". Can it be done using the native ShowDialog class?

Comment: @Cystack I had the same question when reading his answer. What I did was take everything from inside the builder and cut it into a stateful widget. At some point you will probably have something like this... 

return showDialog(context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (context) {
          return SimpleDialog( ...... fill out SimpleDialog

Cut starting at the word "return" and put it in the builder of your stateful widget.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest and least amount of lines:
Use StatefulBuilder as top widget of Content in the AlertDialog.

```
                StatefulBuilder(
                  builder: (context, state) => CupertinoSlider(
                    value: brightness,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      state(() {
                        brightness = val;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ));
```

Answer (score 5):

I've come up with the same issue with a checkbox and that's my solution, even if it's not the best approach. (see the comment in the code)

```
Future<Null>_showDialog() async {
  return showDialog < Null > (
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return new AlertDialog(
        title: Text("title"),
        content: Container(
          height: 150.0,
          child: Checkbox(
            value: globalSearch,
            onChanged: (bool b) {
              print(b);
              globalSearch = b;
              Navigator.of(context).pop(); // here I pop to avoid multiple Dialogs
              _showDialog(); //here i call the same function
            },
          )),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing!!  This really helped me.  I'm trying to do a complex dialog where I have dropdown menus and returning the state to the parent widget of multiple pull downs was stretching my brain.  But this solution appears to work quite well.  Just pop and call the dialog again.

Comment: It cannot be used in the case of a slider because when we slide, the dialog is popped and we dont get the continuity in scrolling

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue and resolved by putting everything under AlertDialog in to a StatefullWidget.

```
    class <your dialog widget> extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FilterDialogState createState() => _FilterDialogState();
}

class _<your dialog widget> extends State<FilterDialog> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      //your alert dialog content here
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a statefull class with the slider at the return time and the double value should declare inside the statefull class thus the setstate func will work.

here is an example i done this for my slider popup its same for alert dialog use can declare the variable as global thus it can be accessed by other classes

```dart
    class _PopupMenuState extends State<PopupMenu> {
      double _fontSize=15.0;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Slider(
            value: _fontSize,
            min: 10,
            max: 100,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                print(value);
                _fontSize = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem and it seen all of the above solution doesn't help me, so I try to solve it and it wok
here my solution :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PopUpWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const PopUpWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<PopUpWidget> createState() => _PopUpWidgetState();
}

class _PopUpWidgetState extends State<PopUpWidget> {
  List<String> img = [
    'assets/images/formImage/team_effort.png',
    'assets/images/formImage/playing_golf.png',
    'assets/images/formImage/phone.png',
    'assets/images/formImage/confirm.png'
  ];
  int value = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, state) => AlertDialog(
        content: Wrap(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: CloseButton(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context, '');
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (value > 0) {
                                value = value - 1;
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Image.asset(img[value]),
                      flex: 2,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (value < 3) {
                                value = value + 1;
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)),
                    ),
                  ],
                ))
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

After that we at that function to the manin class

```
  //Run this function before other
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    updateUI(widget.dataValue);
    PopUpWidget(); 
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_showOpenDialog);

  }
    // show Open Dialog method
  _showOpenDialog(_) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return PopUpWidget();
        });
  }
```